# Using pointers to lines in a file in perl

Tags: perl, sorting, pointers

I'm trying to use some sort of pointers in perl so that I can look at two at two files that are sorted in alphabetical order and match things in both the files if they have the same name in the first column. The way i'm searching through each file though is I'm looking at which lines first column is lower in alphabetical order and then moving the pointer on that file to the next line. Somewhat similar to the pointers in merge sort. The code below is an example of what I want.

Using these two files.

set1

```
 apple  17  20
 boombox  23  29
 carl  25  29
 cat  22  33
 dog  27  44
```

set2

```
 ants  yes
 boombox  no
 carl  yes
 dentist  yes
 dice  no
 dog  no
```

I can make a script that does something like this

```
($name, $affirmation) = first line in set2; #part I'm confused about I just kind of need some sort of command of something that will do this
while (<>){
        @set1 = split;
        while ($name < set1[0]){
             ($name, $affirmation) = next line in set2;  # part i'm confused about I just kind of need some sort of command of something that will do this
        }
        if ($name = $set[0]{
               print @set1, $affirmation;
        }
```

This is how I would run it

```
./script.txt set1
```

I would end up with

```
boombox  23  29  no
carl  25  29  yes
dog  27  44  no
```

.

.

Edit:

I tried some code in some of the answers to see if I could make some functional code out of it but I seem to be running into problems, and some of the syntax in the answers I could not understand so I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to debug or solve this.

This is my specific example using the folllowing two text files

text.txt

```
Apples 0       -1      -1      0       0       0       0       -1 
Apricots 0       1      1      0       0       0       0       1
Fruit        0       -1      -1      0       0       0       0       -1
Grapes        0       -2      -1      0       0       0       0       -2
Oranges   0       1      1      0       0       0       0       -1
Peaches  0       -2      -1      0       0       0       0       -2
```

text2.txt

```
Apples      CHR1    +       1167628 1170420 1       1       N
Apricots      CHR1    -       2115898 2144159 1       1       N
Oranges       CHR1    -       19665266        19812066        1       1      N
Noidberry     CHR1    -       1337728 1329993 1       1       N
Peaches       CHR1    -       1337275 1342693 1       1       N
```

And this script
script.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
my $file_1 = $ARGV[0];
my $file_2 = $ARGV[1];

open my $fh1, '<', $file_1 or die "Can't open $file_1: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', $file_2 or die "Can't open $file_2: $!";

open(my $single, '>', 'text.txt');
open(my $deep, '>', 'text2.txt');
OUTER: while (my $outer = <$fh1>){
        chomp $outer;
        @CopyNumber = split(' ', $outer);
        ($title, $title2) = split('\|', $CopyNumber[0]);
        #print 'title: ',$title,' title2: ',$title2,"\n";
        my $numLoss = 0;
        my $deepLoss = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $#CopyNumber; $i++){
                #print "$CopyNumber[$i], $#CopyNumber, $i, \n";
                if ($CopyNumber[$i] < 0){
                        $numLoss = $numLoss + 1;
                        if ($CopyNumber[$i] <-1){
                                $deepLoss = $deepLoss + 1;
                        }
                }
        }
        if ($GeneSym and (($GeneSym cmp $title)==0)){ #or (($GeneSym cmp $title2)==0))){
                print $single $Chrom,"\t",$Start,"\t",$Stop,"\t",$numLoss/$#CopyNumber,"\n";
                print $deep $Chrom,"\t",$Start,"\t",$Stop,"\t",$deepLoss/$#CopyNumber,"\n";
                next OUTER;
        }

        INNER: while (my $inner = <$fh2>){
                ($GeneSym, $Chrom, $Strand, $Start, $Stop, $MapId, $TotalMap, $AbnormalMerge, $Overlap) = split(' ', $inner);
                $Chrom =~ s/CHR/hs/ee;
                my $cmp = ($GeneSym cmp $title);
                next OUTER if $cmp < 0;
                if ($cmp==0){ #or (($GeneSym cmp $title2)==0)){
                        print $single $Chrom,"\t",$Start,"\t",$Stop,"\t",$numLoss/$#CopyNumber,"\n";
                        print $deep $Chrom,"\t",$Start,"\t",$Stop,"\t",$deepLoss/$#CopyNumber,"\n";
                        next OUTER;
                }
        }
}
```

If I run ./script.pl text.txt text2.txt I should get this printed into Number.txt

//corresponding to columns 2,4,5 of text2.txt and the last column being the percentage of columns which have a number lower than 0

```
hs1     1167628     1170420    0.375 //For Apples
hs1     2115898     2144159    0 //For Apricots
hs1     19665266    19812066   0.125 //For Oranges
hs1     1337275     1342693    0.375 //For Peaches
```

Instead I get this

```
hs1     1167628 1170420 0.375
hs1     2115898 2144159 0
hs1     1337275 1342693 0.375
```

So I'm just getting an error where

```
hs1     19665266    19812066   0.125 //For Oranges
```

isn't printing

Comment: You forgot to state the criterion -- is it that the first word on a line matches (is the same in both files)?  Can you assert anything about the size of either file (both large or not)?

Comment: Both files are large, I'm not quite sure what you mean by assert anything about the size but yes both files are large

Comment: File handles are all the pointers you need!

Comment: @Bob (1) Processing before and inside `INNER` (inside `if ($GenSym ...)` block) need be exactly the same -- we have to do it before as well only so to catch the line from `INNER` that overshoot. Since you have some processing there best put it in a sub. (2) This affects the initialization of `$numLoss` and the other -- they go right after `OUTER` starts, before anything is done.  The way it is now they reset whatever has been computed.  // With these changes I get desired results.  I added comments to my answer (and a missing line of code), and will later add comments on your added code.

Comment: Does the first field of `file1` actually looks like `Apples|XXX`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite like you state, with: use `cmp` for comparison, `split` line into two terms.

For each line of `FILE1` file go through lines of `FILE2` file, exiting when a match is found. Once the `FILE2` overshoots alphabetically move to the next line of `FILE1`.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

sub process {
   my ($name, $affirm_1, $affirm_2) = @_;
   print "$name $affirm_1 $affirm_2\n";
}

my $file_1 = 'set1.txt';
my $file_2 = 'set2.txt';

open my $fh1, '<', $file_1 or die "Can't open $file_1: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', $file_2 or die "Can't open $file_2: $!";

my ($name_2, $affirm_2);
FILE1: while (my $line1 = <$fh1>) {
    chomp $line1;
    my ($name_1, $affirm_1) = split ' ', $line1, 2;

    if ($name_2) {
        my $cmp = $name_1 cmp $name_2;
        next FILE1 if $cmp < 0;
        if ($cmp == 0) {
            process($name_1, $affirm_1, $affirm_2);
            next FILE1;
        }
    }

    FILE2: while (my $line2 = <$fh2>) {
        chomp $line2;
        ($name_2, $affirm_2) = split ' ', $line2, 2;
        my $cmp = $name_1 cmp $name_2;
        next FILE1 if $cmp < 0;
        if ($cmp == 0) {
            process($name_1, $affirm_1, $affirm_2);
            next FILE1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comments on a few remaining details.

Once a `FILE2` line "overshoots," in the next iteration of `FILE1` we need to first check that line, before entering the `FILE2` loop to iterate over its remaining lines. For the first `FILE1` line the `$name_2` is still undef thus `if ($name_2)`.

---

Updated for edited post.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

sub process_line {
    my ($single, $deep, $rline, $GeneSym, $Chrom, $Start, $Stop) = @_;
    my ($numLoss, $deepLoss) = calc_loss($rline);
    $Chrom =~ s/CHR/hs/;
    print $single (join "\t", $Chrom, $Start, $Stop, $numLoss/$#$rline), "\n";
    print $deep   (join "\t", $Chrom, $Start, $Stop, $deepLoss/$#$rline), "\n";
}

sub calc_loss {
    my ($rline) = @_; 
    my ($numLoss, $deepLoss) = (0, 0); 
    for my $i (1.. $#$rline) {
        $numLoss  += 1  if $rline->[$i] < 0;
        $deepLoss += 1  if $rline->[$i] < -1; 
    }   
    return $numLoss, $deepLoss;
}

my ($Number,  $NumberDeep) = ('Number.txt', 'NumberDeep.txt');
open my $single, '>', $Number      or die "Can't open $Number: $!";
open my $deep,   '>', $NumberDeep  or die "Can't open $NumberDeep: $!";

my ($file_1, $file_2) = ('set1_new.txt', 'set2_new.txt');    
open my $fh1, '<', $file_1 or die "Can't open $file_1: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', $file_2 or die "Can't open $file_2: $!";

my ($GeneSym, $Chrom, $Strand, $Start, $Stop, 
    $MapId, $TotalMap, $AbnormalMerge, $Overlap);

FILE1: while (my $line1 = <$fh1>) {
    next if $line1 =~ /^\s*$/;
    chomp $line1;

    my @line = split ' ', $line1;

    if ($GeneSym) {
        my $cmp = $line[0] cmp $GeneSym;
        next FILE1 if $cmp < 0;
        if ($cmp == 0) {
            process_line($single, $deep, \@line,
                         $GeneSym, $Chrom, $Start, $Stop);
            next FILE1;
        }   
    }   

    FILE2: while (<$fh2>) {
        next if /^\s*$/;
        chomp;
        ($GeneSym, $Chrom, $Strand, $Start, $Stop, 
             $MapId, $TotalMap, $AbnormalMerge, $Overlap) = split;
        my $cmp = $line[0] cmp $GeneSym;
        next FILE1 if $cmp < 0;
        if ($cmp == 0) {
            process_line($single, $deep, \@line,
                         $GeneSym, $Chrom, $Start, $Stop);
            next FILE1;
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the desired output with given sample files. Some shortcuts are taken, please let me know if comments would be helpful. Here are a few

- Much error checking should be added around.
- I assume the first field of `FILE1` to be used as it stands. Otherwise changes are needed.
- Processing is split into two functions, calculations being separate. This is not necessary.
- `$#$rline` is the index of the last element of `$rline` arrayref. If this is too much syntax to stomach use `@$rline - 1`, for example as `(0..@$rline-1)`

Some comments on the code posted in the question:

- Always, *always*, please `use warnings;` (and `use strict;`)
- loop over indices is best written `foreach my $i (0..$#array)`
- The regex modifier `/ee` is very involved.  There is absolutely no need for it here.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this out, but i had generalized the code down quite a bit for this question and theres some syntax things here I've never seen before that I don't understand. So i tried to implement in how it made sense to me but I'm getting the error like how I posted in the edit

Comment: @Bob The code in your edit is quite different. Since it's very late here I'll look tomorrow. (On the first pass I don't see why you don't get the first word at least.)  The posted code in this answer works for your original specification -- what syntax (or code) poses problems? I can add explanations.

Comment: I changed my edit, I realized there were some errors in my post before because I wrote it at 3 am, but this one is pretty specific I think @zdim

Comment: @Bob I edited, with some clarifications and an extra line of code that was missing -- if the whole `INNER` is processed without a match, we need to rewind its filehandle for the next line of `OUTER`, what is done with `seek ...`.  Note that processing before `INNER` and inside of it need be exactly the same.

Comment: I've gotten it down so that every line but 'hs1     19665266    19812066   0.125 //For Oranges is being output correctly. I'm not really sure how to use the seek command all I get is the first line 'hs1     1167628     1170420    0.375 //For Apples'. That's when I enter 'seek $fh2, 0, 0;'

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you -- that crept in trying to fix edits to question, which left out a critical part what I didn't notice.  Thank you.

Comment: @ikegami  That code worked fine -- the wrong seek was added to fix the code in the edit of the question.  This code didn't need changes

Comment: @Bob The code in your edit is missing the crucial `next OUTER if $cmp < 0;` -- which is now renamed to `next FILE1 if $cmp < 0;`.  (That's why I had added the `seek`, not noticing the missing part.)  You must have that line, to bail out once overshooting happened.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you for edits!  The sub is far better (thought of it but wanted to keep it simpler), the naming should be clearer this way.  I'l restore comments (only one line was about the bad seek) and check around.  Thank you

Comment: I included the 'next FILE1 if $cmp < 0;' but I'm still just missing the one line in my output for the line for orange

Comment: @Bob I added full working code for your edit and some comments.  Let me know how it goes, in particular whether more comments would be helpful.  I may edit and clean up some more.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you for fixing that bug, and for other improvements.

Comment: `$line[0] cmp $GeneSym` should be `( split /\|/, $line[0] )[0] cmp $GeneSym`

Comment: @ikegami ugh ... thank you.  I am just going to remove that `|` altogether, with a comment asking for clarification.  If it is there should be yet further changes (cmp-ing on both titles, etc)

Comment: @ikegami yes, I saw that -- which is why it makes perfect sense for me to drop-and-note it for now

Answer (score 2):

You're right. It's exactly like a merge sort, except only matching lines are output.

```
sub read_and_parse1 {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   defined( my $line = <$fh> )
      or return undef;

   my ($id, @copy) = split(' ', $line);   # Use split(/\t/, $line) if tab-separated data
   my ($gene_sym) = split(/\|/, $id);

   return [ $gene_sym, @copy ];
}

sub read_and_parse2 {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   defined( my $line = <$fh> )
      or return undef;

   return [ split(' ', $line) ];         # Use split(/\t/, $line) if tab-separated data
}

my $fields1 = read_and_parse1($fh1);
my $fields2 = read_and_parse2($fh2);
while ($fields1 && $fields2) {
   my $cmp = $fields1->[0] cmp $fields2->[0];
   if    ($cmp < 0) { $fields1 = read_and_parse1($fh1); }
   elsif ($cmp > 0) { $fields2 = read_and_parse2($fh2); }
   else {
      my ($gene_sym, @copy) = @$fields1;
      my (undef, $chrom, $strand, $start, $stop, $map_id, $total_map, $abnormal_merge, $overlap) = @$fields2;

      $chrom =~ s/^CHR/hs/;

      my $num_loss  = grep { $_ <  0 } @copy;
      my $deep_loss = grep { $_ < -1 } @copy;

      print($single_fh join("\t", $chrom, $start, $stop, $num_loss/@copy  ) . "\n");
      print($deep_fh   join("\t", $chrom, $start, $stop, $deep_loss/@copy ) . "\n");

      $fields1 = read_and_parse1($fh1);
      $fields2 = read_and_parse2($fh2);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat single.txt
hs1 1167628 1170420 0.375
hs1 2115898 2144159 0
hs1 19665266 19812066 0.125
hs1 1337275 1342693 0.375

$ cat deep.txt
hs1 1167628 1170420 0
hs1 2115898 2144159 0
hs1 19665266 19812066 0
hs1 1337275 1342693 0.25
```